# PHP Trying to use substr to only show last 6 chars in a text file

Tags: php, file, substr

I am new to php. just trying to run this local website.
Trying to pull the last 5 chars from a txt file that is updated every 5 minutes.
this is my script:

```
    <?php 
$temperature = include( "temperaturelog.txt");
$temp = substr($temperature, -5);
print $temp
?>
```

this is my test file:

```
14.75
13.52
```

here is what my webpage shows:

[webpage dispaly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofqDQ.png)

any clues on what i am doing wrong? or misunderstanding the documentation?

Comment: try file_get_contents("temperaturelog.txt") instead of include

Comment: it is still showing both values

Comment: and then a full reboot makes it work, huh, odd.

Comment: If you saw anything from the include, it would probably be the entire file contents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `file_get_contents('fileName')` or `fopen('fileName', 'mode'); fread('fileName', length);`

1st method:

Replace your PHP code to the following:

```
<?php 
$temperature = file_get_contents( "temperaturelog.txt");
$temp = substr($temperature, -5);
print $temp;
?>
```

You can find more information about `file_get_contents()` here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

The 2nd method:

```
<?php 
$fileName = "temperaturelog.txt";
$handle  = fopen($fileName , 'r');
$temperature = fread($handle, filesize($fileName));
$temp = substr($temperature, -5);
print $temp;
?>
```

And for the 2nd method more info:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php

Comment: this solution worked after a full machine reboot, thanks!

Comment: @DarkeFyre13, I updated my answer with another solutions and links to get more info about the used functions

Comment: If my answer helped you, Please consider clicking the tic next to my answer to accept my answer

Answer (score 0):

The immediate issue is that you are using a PHP [include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php). You should only use an include to *include* PHP executable code - that is what the function is for. It won't return the file contents.

A very simple function to achieve similar functionality would be [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php), however don't jump the gun just yet. [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) will read the **whole file** and return it as a string. Very easy and simple, if that's what you want to do - but you only want the **last five characters**. So instead, we can write a tiny bit more code to only read the last five characters. It won't be too difficult, I promise!

First of all, we want to [open](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) a file. This will give us a *file pointer* that we will use to reference that open file in subsequent calls (keep an eye out for it). The following will [open](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) a file in *read only* mode - [documentation for fopen](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php).

```
$fp = fopen('temperaturelog.txt', 'r');
```

Now, we have a file pointer (`$fp`), we can play with this file. But we need to know the [size](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php). There's a number of ways to do this (see [fstat](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fstat.php), for example) but the simplest way is probably with [filesize](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php).

```
$size = filesize('temperaturelog.txt');
```

So now we know the [file size](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php). We are going to perform an operation on the file called [*seek*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fseek.php). Just imagine you have your file open in your text editor, we are going to move the cursor to 5 characters before the end - [documentation for fseek](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fseek.php).

```
$pos = $size - 5;
fseek($fp, $pos);
```

And now that we have set our [position](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fseek.php) in the file, we can [read](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php) until the end of the file. The second parameter of 1024 specifies how many bytes to read from the file. Of course we will only be reading five, however I have set it high to demonstrate how it behaves at the end of a file - see the [documentation for fread](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php) for more information on the second parameter.

```
$text = fread($fp, 1024);
```

Now we have the last 5 characters stored in `$text`, and have hit the end of the file. We could [rewind](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rewind.php) the file pointer, or we could [fseek](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fseek.php) to the start, if we did actually need to.

It is good practice to close the file once we are done. This allows other processes to open it immediately instead of waiting for PHP to close the file itself - [documentation for fclose](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fclose.php).

```
fclose($fp);
```

Laid out in a bunch of snippets, it may look bigger than it actually is, so let's bring all that together:

```
// Open and get size
$fp = fopen('temperaturelog.txt', 'r');
$size = filesize('temperaturelog.txt');

// Seek to just before the end
$pos = $size - 5;
fseek($fp, $pos);

// Read and close
$text = fread($fp, 1024);
fclose($fp);
```

The equivalent with [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php):

```
$size = filesize('temperaturelog.txt');
$file = file_get_contents('temperaturelog.txt');
$text = substr($file, -5);
```

However, you can *expect* the [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) example to be far less scalable. For simple stuff, it works a treat though!